# Making custom tel protocol windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, registry, tel

I'm working on a custom softphone application and running into a problem. I would really like to redirect the `tel:` links to a application on my PC. I have figgured out I need to add my application to the windows TEL; URL:tel option list. However all solutions I'm finding don't seem to work. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) documentation isn't working for me (yes i have restarted multiple times) some peaple say it isn't posible in windows 10 annymore, however there are a few third-party application that are popping up. The applictions are not from the windows store so that can't be the issue either.

The `.reg` export I ended up with looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel]
@="URL:Tel test"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Test\\Test.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Test\\Test.exe" "%1"
```

The goal vissual:
Inside the windows settings on the `tel:` protocol I would like to add my own application (written in `C#`)
[image]

When selected the `.exe` will be called al a `tel:` handeler.

I would really appriciate anny tips towards the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to add the software with the related capability.
Check here for the relevant registry keys:
https://newbedev.com/can-t-change-tel-protocol-handler-in-windows-10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).